# ListDensityPlot interpolation only in one direction

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I am using `ListDensityPlot` to plot a set of graphs, i.e. I have got a rectangular grid. Is there any way how to prevent interpolation along the `y` axis and interpolate data only in the `x` direction? So far I was thinking only about "pre-interpolation" of my dataset before I plot it and then using `InterpolationOrder->0`.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps,

```
data = Table[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3, 1.}, {y, 0, 3, 1.}]; 

ContourPlot[ListInterpolation[data, {{0, 3}, {0, 3}}, 
      InterpolationOrder -> #][x, y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, ContourStyle -> None, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"InterpolationOrder->",#}], ImageSize -> 200] & /@ 
   {{3, 1}, {3,3}, {1, 3}, {3, 0}, {0,0}, {0, 3}} // Grid[Partition[#, 2]] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]